# Are "course" and "lesson" interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, conjunctions, ambiguity

I'm writing a letter to Columbia University but I am having problems with the last sentence of the letter.

> [...] I have also nearly completed the X course that your university offers online.
>
> **With** this **lesson** being the second, and Columbia's former Provost and Dean of Faculties Prof. Jonathan Cole's influential article *On the Matter of Edward Said* that taught me the sanctity of academic freedom being the first **lesson** I **took** from Columbia, I wholeheartedly hope to **take** my next Columbia **course** on campus.

The most problematic parts are in bold. There is a [link](http://columbiaspectator.com/2000/10/20/university-responds-matter-edward-said) to the article for a better understanding of the context, or if anyone is interested.

What I tried to say here is that this article was a personally important moral lesson and the first lesson I took from Columbia; that this online course was the second lesson (in the academic sense) I took from the university; and that I hope to be at Columbia for the next ones.

I tried to condense this meaning into the sentence, but I don't know if using lesson and course practically interchangeably is correct in essence.

I also am not sure if using "with" at the beginning of the sentence is a correct usage.

Any help, opinion, suggestion or even possible rephrasing would be welcome. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Typically, a course would consist of several presentations or 'lessons' *in the academic sense*, as you put it.

Answer (score 1):

'Course' and 'lesson' are almost never interchangeable. Courses tend to consist of lessons, as Lawrence said.

Using ‘with’ at the beginning of a sentence is not unusual but it’s rarely necessary, it can be  restrictive and it can easily make things far too complicated. It certainly does that here where even without a formal analysis, you seem to be essaying at least a dozen points at one time.

From courses *containing* lessons, it should follow that a course can’t *be* a lesson. Thus ‘this lesson being the second… ' is doubly questionable.

First, presumably ‘this lesson…’ refers to the ‘X course’ from the previous paragraph, so it should use 'that.'

Then, while a course can’t be a lesson, it could provide or offer or more obviously, *contain* a lesson.

Neither nit matters greatly by itself but with more to be picked from 12 other points, the possible permutations of problems could prove prohibitive.

My suggestion would be to practice rephrasing the whole; pick at least three other versions and experiment. Apart from the abbreviation ‘Prof.’ how many stops present themselves as useful options?